# Why can't I enable software RAID on a pair of SD cards in Windows XP Embedded?

Tags: sd-card, software-raid, windows-xp-embedded, removable-media

I was hoping to set up software raid between a pair of SD cards (for redundancy) in an embedded device but as I understand it, I need to upgrade them to dynamic drives to do this.

The cards appear under 'Disk drives' in device manager and as drive D: / E: in 'My Computer'. If I look under 'Control Panel' > 'Administrative Tools' > 'Computer Management' > 'Disk Management', however, I can't see my SD card.

Is this simply not possible because SD Cards are considered removable media and windows isn't set up to allow it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, SD cards are considered removable, and as such will not be RAID'able.